# gnupg File Encryption using C#.net

Tags: gnupg

i have requirement to do gnupg file encryption in .Net Console application . source system already shared me the public key , using the public key i need to encrypt the ZIP folder using  gnupg file encryption in .NET Console application programmatically.

i tried searching in google don't find much resources. if anyone has done the requirement please share the steps / code base samples.

I tried searching in Github for source code found gpg.net class library but don't have much documentation of how to use it.